# Imagemagick convert to name tiles as row/column doesn't work as expected with -extent

Tags: imagemagick, crop, imagemagick-convert

I have an image, 5120  ×  4352  that I crop into 2048x2048 tiles. I want to name my cropped tiles like

- tile_0_0.png
- tile_0_1.png
- tile_0_2.png
- tile_1_0.png
- tile_1_1.png
- tile_1_2.png
- ...

But this command:

```
convert image.png -crop 2048x2048 -gravity northwest \ 
-extent 2048x2048 -transparent white  \ 
-set 'filename:tile' '%[fx:page.x/2048]_%[fx:page.y/2048]'  \ 
+repage +adjoin 'tile_%[filename:tile].png'
```

Gives me this result:

- tile_0_0.png
- tile_0_1.png
- tile_0_16.png
- tile_1_0.png
- tile_1_1.png
- tile_1_16.png
- tile_4_0.png
- tile_4_1.png
- tile_4_16.png

I suspect it has do with the tiles on the last row and column aren't fully 2048x2048, but the extent command makes the end result still 2048, but how can I use this with tiles and file names?

My current workaround is to first resize the original image like this, and then run the above command:

```
convert image.png -gravity northwest \
-extent 2048x2048 -transparent white bigger.png
```

But it would be nice to do it in one swoop :)

Comment: I do not think you can do that in one command with Imagemagick. But you can pipe the output of the extent to the input of the crop so that you do not have to save the intermediate extended image to disk. You might look at my script, overlapcrop, which will allow you to discard the odd sized edge pieces. It has several modes of operation and you can overlap the tiles. My web site is http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/index.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using ImageMagick you could set a viewport that is just enough larger than the input image so it divides evenly by 2048. Then a no-op distort will enlarge the viewport to that size. That way the "-crop 2048x2048" will create pieces that are already 2048 square.

Here's a sample command I worked up in Windows, and I'm pretty sure I translated it to work correctly as a *nix command.

```
convert image.png \
   -set option:distort:viewport '%[fx:w-(w%2048)+2048]x%[fx:h-(h%2048)+2048]' \
   -virtual-pixel none -distort SRT 0 +repage -crop 2048x2048 \
   -set 'filename:tile' '%[fx:page.x/2048]_%[fx:page.y/2048]' \
   +repage +adjoin 'tile_%[filename:tile].png'
```

The "-distort SRT" operation does nothing except expand the viewport to dimensions that divide evenly by 2048, with a result just like doing an "-extent" before the crop. And "-virtual-pixel none" will leave a transparent background in the overflow areas.

Edited to add: The formula for extending the viewport in the above command will incorrectly add another 2048 pixels even if the dimension is already divisible by 2048. It also gives an incorrect result if the dimension is less than 2048. Consider using a formula like this for setting the viewport to handle those conditions...

```
'%[fx:w+(w%2048?2048-w%2048:0)]x%[fx:h+(h%2048?2048-h%2048:0)]'
```

Comment: Thanks! Didn’t try it yet but it looks good and the modulo operator is what I used in php to calculate the canvas size when doing it in two steps.

Comment: There's a minor error in the formula in my example command that gives incorrect results in some circumstances. See my added edit for a correction.